# How can I upload a directory full of artifacts to GitHub Packages?

Tags: github

***Executive summary:*** I'd like to, if possible, just upload a directory full of files to a "GitHub Package". Not a GitHub "repository", but a "Github Package", which are described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/publishing-and-managing-packages/about-github-packages). Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't tell you how to do such a thing. It only tells you how to upload build artifacts using build tools for JavaScript, Ruby, Java, and .NET.

Why do I want to do this? I answer this immediately below. Though if there is also an easy solution using Maven, then Maven will also work for me:

We're hoping to migrate from a locally-hosted Nexus artifact repository to GitHub Packages as a way of making our build artifacts (e.g., jar files) available to everyone in our development team.

The programming language we're using is Scala, which is a JVM-targeted language, so it's designed to largely interoperate with the Java ecosystem. For managing builds, however, we use sbt, not Maven. Sbt is the standard Scala build tool.

There is a plugin for sbt (called sbt-github-packages), which actually works great. It allows us to easily publish our Scala jar files, etc., to GitHub just by typing "sbt publish".

The problem that we have yet to solve, however, is uploading to a GitHub Package third-party artifacts, such as Oracle's jdbc drivers. This is not a problem for most third-party artifacts, since most of them are stored in publicly available Maven or Ivy artifact repositories, and sbt will just automatically fetch them as needed.

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't provide their jdbc drivers in such a standard way. There are also other artifacts we need to use that we don't author and which are not located in public artifact repositories. We currently solve this problem by uploading them into our locally-hosted Nexus artifact repository.

The instructions on GitHub for publishing artifacts to GitHub Packages say only to cd into your Java source code Git repo and type "mvn deploy". (You have to add some config stuff to the pom file first, but that's easy enough.) But these instructions are intended for compiling Java source code and then publishing the compiled artifacts into the GitHub Package. They are not complete instructions that tell you how to deal with the case where you don't have source code, but instead have only prebuilt artifacts.

I'm sure that if I understood Maven well, I could probably figure out how to make this work, but I know very, very little about Maven. As I mentioned above, we use sbt instead.

I did get something to work, but it's not quite right. I made a directory with all of Oracle's ojdbc7 artifacts. I made a symlink from ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom to pom.xml and then I ran "mvn deploy". This ***did*** upload  ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar and ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom to the GitHub Package, but other artifacts were not uploaded. For instance, this did not upload ojdbc7-12.1.0.2-javadoc.jar.

Also, if there were a source-code jar in this directory, I'm sure that it also wouldn't have been uploaded.

If anyone knows what I need to do to publish to the GitHub Package all of the artifacts in my ojdbc7 directory, I will be very thankful.

Comment: https://github.com/features/packages and then https://lab.github.com/githubtraining/github-actions:-publish-to-github-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Nirmala in a different answer here, what I'm trying to do may no longer be necessary specifically for Oracle jdbc artifacts. (I haven't tried his answer out to see if it works for us.) But there are other third-party artifacts that we may wish to place into a GitHub Package. I have figured out how to accomplish this. Here is example of me uploading an ojdbb7 javadoc artifact to a GitHub Package:

```
$ mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy-file \
     -DpomFile=pom.xml \
     -Dfile=ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar \
     -Dfiles=ojdbc7-12.1.0.2-javadoc.jar \
     -Dclassifiers=javadoc \
     -Dtypes=jar \
     -Durl=https://maven.pkg.github.com/myCompany/myRepo \
     -DrepositoryId=github
```

`-Dfiles` can contain a comma-separated list of files that you wish to upload in addition to the object code artifact.

`-Dclassifiers` is a comma-separated list of things like "javadoc" and "sources", etc. You need to specify one for each artifact that you include in `-Dfiles`.

`-Dtypes` is a comma-separated list of all the file extensions that you are including in your upload. (Other than "pom.xml".) In this case, we are only uploading jar files (and "pom.xml"), so we only need to specify "jar".

`-Durl` specifies the repository that you want to upload to. It must start with "https://maven.pkg.github.com".

`-DrepositoryId` must be "github".

It's natural when looking at the Maven command line that I have provided, to wonder what's up with `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy-file`. One would think that you could safely use the more sane invocation `deploy:deploy-file` instead.

Unfortunately, if you don't specify the plugin version as I have above, you end up getting an old version of the plugin that doesn't work. (At least not at the time that I am writing this.)

Comment: It does not work for me. I am constantly getting a `422 Unprocessable Entity` error. Regardless I am trying to upload a simple JAR+POM or JAR+POM+SOURCES

Answer (score 1):

Oracle JDBC drivers are already available in Central Maven. YOu should use Central Maven.
Refer to the instructions on this [page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html).

The below GAV will get JDBC driver along with all the other complimentary jars.

```
<groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc<groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc8-production</artifactId>
<version>19.7.0.0</version>
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer helps with one particular issue, Oracle's jdbc drivers that are more recent than ojdbc7. But it doesn't help with the more general problem, which I still have for other artifacts that are currently only available in our locally-hosted Nexus and which I need to migrate to GitHub Packages.